# How to setup my keyboard layot to match the characters on the physical keyboard

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I have Thinkpad T540p with Windows 8.1 installed. With US English keyboard set but i can't match some of the special characters because they are in different place psysically and only the letters and numbers are in place. Do i need to install something to make that change with some 3 party software or within the system? Can they match the exact place of the key and the character with it?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post a photo or something?

Comment: It has characters such like Æ-Ø-Å and the dashes the brackets are not in the same place virtually for example if i press ":" it shows as "_" and the whole keyboard is like that. It has difference between the place of the characters on the psysical keys and the ones on the OS layot.

Comment: Where the computer comes from? Looks like a Norwegian keyboard, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdno.html

Answer (score 1):

If @ is on key with 2, it could be US keyboard layout.
[British and American keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards)

To change keyboard layout [Change your keyboard layout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17424/windows-change-keyboard-layout)